# Jenkins git push multiple branches

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, push

I have a Jenkins job made of a shell script that I use to manage my git flow. That script connects via SSH to the remote git repo, and makes changes to branches `dev` and `master`. I want it to push those two branches back to the remote repo.

The Git Publisher post build actions let you push HEAD to one remote branch, but does not allow pushing multiple branches](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21681).

I tried doing a "git push" from the shell script but I get "Permission denied (publiuc key)". In the build log, I can see that Jenkins uses a plugin to inject SSH credentials for pre-build and post-build actions:

```
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@my.repo.url:path/to/repo/test.git
 > git init /home/jenkins/workspace/node-injection/release # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@my.repo.url:path/to/repo/test.git
...
Seen branch in repository origin/dev
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
# ... do some work
+ git push origin master dev --follow-tags
Fetching origin
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Is there a way to pass SSH credentials to the shell script so it can `git push` ?

I don't want to pass a user/password to the shell script because that would force me to create a one user per repository I manage, while I can have multiple deploy keys for a single user (which is much easier to manage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding an answer:

1. When you create SSH credentials for a git repository: [**don't use a passphrase**](https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password).
2. In your Jenkins job configuration, check "Use secret text(s) or file(s)" and add an "SSH Credentials" entry with the needed credentials. In the "Key File Variable" field, enter `GIT_SSH_KEYS_PATH`.
3. Inject the ssh credentials for every command that require it like so:

   ```
   GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i $GIT_SSH_KEYS_PATH" <git-command>
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i $GIT_SSH_KEYS_PATH" git push origin master dev --follow-tags
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to pass SSH credentials to the shell script so it can git push ?

You can use [sshagent plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/#ssh-agent-plugin) to inject credentials context into your shell script execution (relevant fragment of [pipeline script](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) sample):

```
stage('Build') {
        steps {
            sshagent(['a1b36f46-341c-4ffd-941f-5f2fd547d8f8']) {
                sh "./my-git-push-script.sh"
            }
        }
    }
```

As a result an sshagent session will be established with a given credential and if successful a shell script will be exacted. Git push command will utilize this ssh session to communicate to the SCM.

Note: that you have to provide [previously setup credential unique identifier](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/) in Jenkins